# read selected variable and then send back from table to controller

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having a table with data from database called through codeigniter controller.What I want to do is read the selected value from within the table send it back to the controller and use those values to retrieve new records from DB and then load them on again into the page.

**My Controller:**

```
<?php
  if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

     class Dashboard1 extends CI_Controller {

      public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
         $this->load->model('dash_match_model');
         $this->session->keep_flashdata('supplier_id');
        $this->load->helper('url');
          $this->load->database();
    }

    public function index() {
       $arr['page']='dash1';
       $arr['present_all_suppliers'] = $this->dash_match_model->dash_present_all_suppliers();

        $arr['supplierCompany'] = "";

            $this->load->view('clients/clDashboard',$arr);

    }

    public function select_supplier() {

        $supplierCompany = $this->input ->post('supplierCompany');
        $arr['present_all_suppliers'] = $this->dash_match_model->dash_present_all_suppliers();
        $arr['supplierCompany'] = $supplierCompany;

        $supplier_selected = $this->user_model->return_selected_supplier($supplierCompany);
            foreach($supplier_selected->result() as $row)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('supplier_id', $row->supplier_id);


            }

        $this->load->view('unspscSegment',$arr);
    }
}
```

Specific lines of table of my view file:

```
<table id="suppliertable" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Open Range</th>
            <th>Fill Content</th>
            <th>Total Match</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($present_all_suppliers as $v): ?>
            <tr>

                <td onclick="window.location = 'http://example.com'" class="center" style="color:#0c595b;"> <?php echo $v->supplierCompany; ?> </td>
                <td class="center"></td>
                <td class="center"></td>
                <td class="center"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do that with javascript so when i select a supplier (value) to get the selected value and sent it to the controller? Then what should I modify to the controller in order to send the value to the model and collect it and reload them in the view?

Comment: Off topic I would remove this $this->load->database(); and autoload database in application/config/autoload.php you would need to set up sessions I think'

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. I want to send data back from datatables to codeigniter controller. How could I do that with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.ajax()

Implemented in your code:

Script:

```
<script>
    $(".supplier_edit").click(function(){
        var supplier_company = $(this).find('input').val()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://example.com/'+'Dashboard1/select_supplier',
            data: {supplierCompany: supplier_company},
            success: function(result) {
                $("#content").html(result)
            }
        })
        return false
    })
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($present_all_suppliers as $v): ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="supplier_edit" style="color:#0c595b;"><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $v->supplierCompany; ?>" ></td>
            <td class="center"></td>
            <td class="center"></td>
            <td class="center"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>

<div id="content">content from the controller</div>
```

Comment: Hello .Thanks for your reply. I have used jquery but the data from the database are not presented in the table now and it it is return to the controller.

Comment: are the data from database not presented in the table after ajax is run?

If the ajax is success, the table will not be changed. Only inner html id="content" will be changed

Comment: yes the data from the database are not presented in the table after ajax is run.

Comment: Actually I have deleted the type="hidden" in order to see the database values. Now how can I see/read the selected value of the database?

Comment: now the problem is that the click method is not working. Tou can't click any of these values in the table .

Comment: try to use "alert(supplier_company)" in the script after click function. And check whether it return any value or not.

Comment: Now I found  way to read the selected value of the URL by using that <?php  echo base_url(); ?>dashboard1/select_supplier/<?php echo $v->supplierCompany;?>"> . and in the url is presented the selected value.  http://etradesystem/dashboard1/select_supplier/Micro-P . Could you please give me any suggestions on how to get the value Micro-p from the URL and send it to the controller?

Comment: you can add in ajax data 
var micro_p = ""

data: {supplierCompany: supplier_company, microP : microP},

Comment: Perhaps ask separate Question, if the original question has been solved.